# Moving vertical scroll bar on keyboard navigation in custom div dropdown

Tags: javascript, jsp, html, drop-down-menu, keyboard-events

I am navigating through the options in a dropdown( simulated using div) using the keyboard navigation(up, down and enter keys). I want the scroll bar to move and adjust to show the option properly as i navigate using keyboard.

If anyone can give in their insight, It will be helpful, much appreciated.

I have to use pure Javascript, no Jquery can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. However I have fixed down key selection issue. with below formula

```
element.find('SCROLLABLE_COMPONENT_SELECTOR').scrollTop((angular.element('SELECTED_OPTION_SELECTOR').index() * angular.element('SELECTED_OPTION_SELECTOR').outerHeight(true)) - angular.element('SCROLLABLE_COMPOENENT_SELECTOR').height() + 40);
```

above code, will work like .. it will scroll until bottom of your dropdown. Once dropdown bottom reached, selection fixed at the bottom and move the scroll top.

For downkey, I am working on this. Will post you the updates, If I manage to fix it.

Thanks,
Jay